# get requested ajax url with $.ajaxsetup complete

Tags: ajax, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement google analytics code into our system that is mainly ajax driven calls. I have setup $.ajaxSetup to handle some default ajax behaviour and want to pass the requested url to the analytics function, namely pageTracker._trackPageview("url"); so as to not implement this everywhere a call is made.

Appreciate any help thanks! ;)
Charl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably referring to [extending ajax with prefilters](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/).

Prefilters:

> A prefilter is a callback function that is called before each request
>   is sent, and prior to any $.ajax() option handling.

Example:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
  pageTracker._trackPageview(options.url);      
});
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: Ah brilliant @shanabus! ;) Works 100%

Answer (score 1):

this is what i do :

```
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        'success': function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', jqXHR.requestURL]);
        }
     });

    $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
        jqXHR.requestURL = options.url;   
    });
```

not tested in production, but works normally.

thanks shanabus, it really help me ;)